# Accessing JSON data in Angular application (Multiple nested arrays)

Tags: json, angular

How can I access 'line' data from the given object?
This is the link to api -https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/api/odds/v1/leagues/3/offers/gamelines.json

```
{
    "events": [{
        "id": 153502679,
        "name": "Green Bay Packers @ Chicago Bears",
        "homeTeamName": "CHI Bears",
        "awayTeamName": "GB Packers",
        "startDate": "2019-09-06T00:20:00.0000000Z",
        "offers": [{
            "id": "1-2160521227",
            "label": "Point Spread",
            "outcomes": [{
                "id": "1-2568051855",
                "label": "GB Packers",
                "line": "+3.5000",
                "oddsAmerican": "-110",
                "oddsDecimal": 1.9100,
                "oddsFractional": "10/11",
                "participant": "GB Packers"
            },
```

I am getting

```
<td>{{data.name }}</td>
        <td>{{data.homeTeamName }}</td>
        <td>{{data.awayTeamName}}</td>
        <td>{{data.startDate }}</td>
        <!--<td>{{data.offers[1].label }}</td>-->
        <td>{{data.offers.outcomes[2].line }}</td>
```

I tried the above code to access line in outcomes object by it give me below error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not accessing the data in the offers Array.

Please, try the following code to access the events, then the offers and then the outcomes:

```
data.events[0].offers[0].outcomes[0].line
```

Hope it works!

Comment: You're right. I have updated the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Provided Api response contains 3 nested Arrays. So you have to consider them while accessing their values. Depending on the number of items you have in the array below solution will vary. In your example, You are accessing values of the first item of array 'Events', 'offers', 'outcomes'.

In this specific case, You may try

`<td>{{data.events[0].offers[0].outcomes[0].line}} </td>`

Comment: It worked, can you explain why did you take 0 index?

Comment: Because its an array. How else would it know to take the first element?

Comment: Would'nt offers[0] would be pointing to first index which is id?

Comment: @AshishShah Array starts with index 0. So when you want to access first item of the Array, you need to point to Index 0. For 2nd item in the array, index 1. For 3rd item in the array , index 2 and so forth. Remember, When dealing with Arrays its always use index length-1. For Example, Array of 5 items will have max index of 4 which is length-1.

Comment: @AshishShah No. offers[0].id will return id.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have just one item in each nested aray, you can access `line` as

```js
let data = {
    "events": [{
        "id": 153502679,
        "name": "Green Bay Packers @ Chicago Bears",
        "homeTeamName": "CHI Bears",
        "awayTeamName": "GB Packers",
        "startDate": "2019-09-06T00:20:00.0000000Z",
        "offers": [{
            "id": "1-2160521227",
            "label": "Point Spread",
            "outcomes": [{
                "id": "1-2568051855",
                "label": "GB Packers",
                "line": "+3.5000",
                "oddsAmerican": "-110",
                "oddsDecimal": 1.9100,
                "oddsFractional": "10/11",
                "participant": "GB Packers"
                
            }]
        }]
    }]
}

console.log(data.events[0].offers[0].outcomes[0].line);
```

If there are n number of objects in each nested array, you can do as

```js
let data = {
    "events": [{
        "id": 153502679,
        "name": "Green Bay Packers @ Chicago Bears",
        "homeTeamName": "CHI Bears",
        "awayTeamName": "GB Packers",
        "startDate": "2019-09-06T00:20:00.0000000Z",
        "offers": [{
            "id": "1-2160521227",
            "label": "Point Spread",
            "outcomes": [{
                "id": "1-2568051855",
                "label": "GB Packers",
                "line": "+3.5000",
                "oddsAmerican": "-110",
                "oddsDecimal": 1.9100,
                "oddsFractional": "10/11",
                "participant": "GB Packers"
                
            }]
        }]
    }]
}


data['events'].forEach(event => {
    event.offers.forEach(offer => {
        offer.outcomes.forEach(outcome => {
          console.log(outcome.line);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Why 0 as index? Would'nt offers[0] would be pointing to first index which is id?

Comment: @AshishShah offers is an array of object where `offers[0]` would gove you the whole object.